# Making a static reference to a non-static method from inside the method

Tags: java, static, static-methods, non-static

I understand the "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" error, but I came across with this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();        

        while (true) {
            myClassInstance.myMethod();
            myMethod();//Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method myMethod()
        }       
    }// END main

    void myMethod() {
        try {
            //Stuff 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            myMethod();
        }
    }// END myMethod

}// END MyCLass
```

I can't just call `myMethod()` from `main` but I can do it from inside the method itself (in this case I want to call `myMethod()` again if an exception happens).

How does this work? is `myClassInstance` still somehow there because at that point I'm still inside `myMethod()`?
Would it be better to have  `static MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass()` at class level and then call `myClassInstance.myMethod()` every time?

Comment: of course you can't. The other method is part of an instance of the class MyClass and not the class itself. You really should learn about class and object methods

Comment: myMethod is an **instance** method. Calling is using `myMethod()` is equivalent to `this.myMethod()`. Inside myMethod(), which is an instance method,  `this` exists: it's the current object. Inside main(), which is a **static** method, there is no  `this`. So the call doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know more about static and non-static methods:

> A static method belongs to the class
>   and a non-static method belongs to an
>   object of a class. That is, a
>   non-static method can only be called
>   on an object of a class that it
>   belongs to. A static method can
>   however be called both on the class as
>   well as an object of the class. A
>   static method can access only static
>   members. A non-static method can
>   access both static and non-static
>   members because at the time when the
>   static method is called, the class
>   might not be instantiated (if it is
>   called on the class itself). In the
>   other case, a non-static method can
>   only be called when the class has
>   already been instantiated. A static
>   method is shared by all instances of
>   the class. These are some of the basic
>   differences. I would also like to
>   point out an often ignored difference
>   in this context. Whenever a method is
>   called in C++/Java/C#, an implicit
>   argument (the 'this' reference) is
>   passed along with/without the other
>   parameters. In case of a static method
>   call, the 'this' reference is not
>   passed as static methods belong to a
>   class and hence do not have the 'this'
>   reference.

**Reference**:[Static Vs Non-Static methods](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joydip/archive/2006/09/17/Static-vs-Non-_2D00_-Static-Methods.aspx)

> How does this work? is `myClassInstance` still somehow there because at
>   that point I'm still inside `myMethod()`?

`myMethod` is an instance method that belongs to `myClassInstance`. so when you call `myMethod()` inside `myMethod()` it's equivalent to `this.myMethod()`

> Would it be better to have  `static MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass()` at class level and then call `myClassInstance.myMethod()` every time?

When we declare a member of a class as static it means no matter how many objects of the class are created, there is only one copy of the static member. A static member is shared by all objects of the class. All static data is initialized to zero when the first object is created, if no other initialization is present. For more information visit [Static Variables : Good or Bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492969/static-variables-good-or-bad).