# I'm trying to understand how "calling an object's method" works in Java, but it's confusing me

Tags: java

I've currently been reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) 3 times now, and I am having a hard time applying what is written to my own simple program. I'm trying to understand on a fundamental level why exactly I am writing `p.add(v);` in my code below.

I declare an object `p`, and an object `v` with the values of 5 and 17 respectively. My method `add` then adds the two values together. I takes on the argument `v` so I understand that the object `v` has to be in the brackets of `add(v)` when I refer to it in my main method. However I'm having a hard time explaining in words why I need to call on the method `add` with respect to `p` here. Isn't `p` also an argument like `v`? Why can't I just change my method to be:

```
public void add(Positive v, Positive p)
```

And then call it by saying `add(v,p);`?

According to the java documentation, I need to call on a method when the object is outside of my class? But everything here is inside my class? So I'm not sure what it is exactly that they're trying to say in the documentation.

```
public class Positive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Positive p = new Positive(5);
            Positive v = new Positive(17);
            p.add(v);
            System.out.println(p.get());
    }
    private int n;

    public Positive(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void add(Positive v)
    {
        this.n += v.get();
    }

    public int get() {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: The static method `main` is not "inside" your class so when you create an object there it will be outside of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, You got a class named `Positive`, there you got a `public static void main` function.
As you remember, Java programs start executing at the main method (read a bit this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java).

so, when you run this method you will execute the following:

`Positive p = new Positive(5);
Positive v = new Positive(17);`

here you initiate 2 class instances, `p` and `v` by using the `new` operator (which, calls the constructor method).

`p` and `v` are two different instances of `Positive`.

each `p` and `v` has the methods listed in this class (here its `add` and `get`) each of them is unique to the each instance.

then you get the field `n` from `v` using the   `get` method of `v` and add it to the `n` member of `p` (read more about instance methods vs static methods here: read more here about: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/)
also read about java access levels for members (https://www.programcreek.com/2011/11/java-access-level-public-protected-private/)

now you wanna execute the `add` method of `p` by doing [first you will execute the `get` method of `v`]:

`p.add(v.get())`;

because both of them are non static methods, they belongs to an instance, therefore you need this syntax.

;;;

regarding `add(p,v)`; if `add` was declared as `static` and the arguments were `Positive p, Positive v` then you could do something like you suggested:

```
public class Positive {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Positive p = new Positive(5);
    Positive v = new Positive(17);
    int result = add(p,v);
    System.out.println(result);
}
private int n;

public Positive(int n) {
    this.n = n;
}

public static int add(Positive p, Positive v)
{
    return p.get() + v.get();
}

public int get() {
    return n;
}
}
```

read more about static/instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

This call adds `v`'s value *into* `p`.

if you just add `v and p` together where do you want to store the result?

What this call does, is to increment the private value `n` of your instance `p` by the value of `v`.

Simple said:

Start with:
p = 5
v = 17

p.add(v) means: p = 22 (5 of p + 17 of v added) *and stored in p*. So p is now 22.
call p.add(v) again and it will again increase p's value by 17, making it 39 total.

v is still 17 all the time.

just for fun you could call:
p.add(v)
p.add(v)
v.add(p)

the first two adds bring p to 39 as I said above, if you now add p into v, you add those 39 to the 17 of v and *store the result in v* (because you invoke `v.add`).
v is 56 then.

I hope this makes it a bit clearer what the method calls to.
Cheers Gris

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a static method that covers `public void add(Positive v, Positive p)` like this:

```
public static void add(Positive v, Positive p)
{
    p.n += v.get();
}
```

Please also read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682750/making-a-static-reference-to-a-non-static-method-from-inside-the-method/53682923#53682923) that will explain more about calling from objects and static calls.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between `p` as an argument to `add(v,p)` and `p` as the object on which the method `add(v)` is invoked.

When you look at `p` as an object, a `Positive`, then it becomes distinct from the number that it holds.
In common terms, we say that `p` is a `Positive` object holding a number `n`. The number (`n`) in the `Positive` object can change while `p`, the object itself remains the same.

In other words, `add(v,p)` would be adding two `Positive`s (and would be typically defined as a `static` method), whereas `p.add(v)` would be modifying the number on the positive `p` (typically declared as an instance method)..

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `static` and non-`static` methods.

Static methods are basically regular methods with some additional access permissions.

Non-static methods on the other hand receive an additional hidden "`this`" parameter, with which you convey the *context* of the call. That way you can implement OOP features like encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism.

For example, the non-static method `Positive.add(Positive v)` could be made `virtual` and be overridden in a subclass `ComplexPositive`. Then you can continue working with `Positive` objects, but the calls to `add()` will depend on each *instance* of the object. You can't achieve that easily with static methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start from the *class*.

A *class* is a set of data and methods.

The *methods* are a kind of message you can sent to an object of the type of a specific *class*.

Those messages can be a query, that returns to you a some of the data contained in that object or just the data in a different format.

Or you can send a command to an object, in order to change the data contained in the object.

What is the *object*?

It is just an instance of your *class*, that means it is a part of memory that contains specific data organized in the way you have defined your class.

In you code example, you're defining a class *Positive* that represent an integer that can be added.

So you write a command *add(Positive p)* and a query *get()*.

The *main()* method in Java is a special method that is used from the JVM at runtime to execute your program.

It is an entrypoint.

As Java is based on classes everything should be placed inside a class, so even the *main()* method.

Why you have to call a method in order to add 2 Positive?

The reason is because you want to hide the details about this operation.

In your case is trivial as it is only a sum of integers, but in a normal case can be very complex and you don't want the logic to be spread all around your code base.

So you put the logic to query and change the data inside classes to avoid complexity and issues when you add new feature or just fix a bug.

In your scenario there is no reason to write a class with methods, you can just do it inside the main method with the same result:

```
public class Positive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 17;
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

Or Just:

```
public class Positive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(5+17);
    }
}
```