# Preferred way of accessing variables from WPF App class

Tags: c#, wpf

In the following code I'm declaring application level `static` variable and then accessing it from `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. Should using static variable here be avoided and instead instantiate the `App class` in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` code below first and use the variable there as `var app = Application.Current as App; app.myVariable = "Some Value";`. I've read at some places (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7346496/1232087)) that `generally` we should avoid using static variables.

**App.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static string myVarialbe {get; set;}
    ...........
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  ..........
  private void btnUserUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    App.myVariable = "Some value";
    ......
  }
}
```

Comment: The post you are referencing [Using Static method and variables - Good vs Bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346496/using-static-method-and-variables-good-vs-bad) already has answer. You defined a property, not a filed. So, everything okay. You can add synchronization if needed.

Comment: @Jackdaw Yes, in the answer to that linked post , when I read the sentence `it seems like you are abusing the static keyword slightly`, I saw a yellow (if not red) light blinking. But your point is well taken - I forgot to notice that there the OP is using field (and not a property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `App` is not a static class and an instance of that class is already accessible via the static `Application.Current` property, there is not need to declare any of its properties static.

Instead, declare non-static properties like

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and access them like this:

```
((App)Application.Current).MyProperty = "Some value";
```

---

As a note, you should avoid using the `as` operator without checking the result for `null`, like

```
var app = Application.Current as App;
app.MyProperty = "Some Value";
```

because that would result in a NullReferenceException instead of an InvalidCastException, which is what you actually want to get in case the cast operation fails.

In a potential situation where `as` may validly return null, test for it:

```
var app = Application.Current as App;
if (app != null)
{
    app.MyProperty = "Some Value";
}
```

Comment: This did the trick (thank you) : `instance of App class is already accessible via the static Application.Current property`. No need to declare `myVariable` as static property

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Clemens answer, I prefer it the following way:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static App Me => ((App) Application.Current);

    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething() { }
    ...
}
```

By that you don't have to write that casting stuff everywhere. You can now simply write code like this:

```
App.Me.MyProperty1 = "some value";
App.Me.MyProperty2 = 5;
App.Me.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge (my upvote) - I should try your suggestion ,as well. Your suggestion helps avoid casting stuff at multiple place.